# Android: How to allow sharing and know inside the app what was shared

Tags: java, android, eclipse, callback, addthis

Could you please tell me what is the best method for allowing the users of my android app to share a Url.

The sharing must enable me to know what they shared from inside the app.

Thanks

Jennie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the AddThis android SDK, then you must provide the SDK with the share url/title/description yourself.

```
String myUrl = "http://www.example.com";
AddThis.shareItem(this, "twitter", myUrl,"Title","Description");
```

In this example, you know that `myUrl` was shared, because that is what you told the API to share.

Comment: Oh I can't believe I did not see this. I can use the URL I want to store information and redirect. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: But it would work only when people share. 

How do I know what they decided to share inside the app? 

Is there an onShare event or something?

Comment: You might want to create a button which can handle a click event. Inside your click handler, call `AddThis.shareItem()`. What the person meant to share depends on your apps UI and state. If you put a share button next to an article, the share button should probably share that article, but it is up to you as the developer to ensure that.